# Controller not found cakephp 3

Tags: php, cakephp-3.0, php-5.6

I am new to cakephp. I just created a project `test` in cake php using below line

```
php composer.phar create-project --prefer-dist cakephp/app test
```

After that I import this project in netbeans

I changed the database configuration in `config/app.php` (just changed the user name and password)

When I ran the project all was good and cakephp page was there.

Now I followed a tutorial from internet and created three file

src/controller/PostsController.php

```
<?php

class PostsController extends \App\Controller\AppController {
   public $helpers = array('Html', 'Form');



    public function index() {
         $this->set('posts', $this->Post->find('all'));
    }

    public function view($id = null) {
        if (!$id) {
            throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid post'));
        }

        $post = $this->Post->findById($id);
        if (!$post) {
            throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid post'));
        }
        $this->set('post', $post);
    }
}

?>
```

`src/Model/Post.php`

```
<?php

class Post extends AppModel {

}

?>
```

`src/View/Posts/index.ctp`

```
<html>
<body>
<h1>Blog posts</h1>

<?php foreach ($posts as $post): ?>
<p><?php echo $post['Post']['title']; ?> | <?php echo $post['Post']['created']; ?>

<?php endforeach; ?>
<?php unset($post); ?>
    </body>

 </html>
```

Also I changed 2 lines in `config/routes.php`

```
 $routes->connect('/', ['controller' => 'Posts', 'action' => 'index', 'home']);

/**
 * ...and connect the rest of 'Pages' controller's URLs.
 */
$routes->connect('/posts/*', ['controller' => 'Posts', 'action' => 'index']);
```

When I goto url http://localhost:8888/test/post or http://localhost:8888/test or http://localhost:8888/test/posts

Always I get the error

```
Error: PostController could not be found.
Error: Create the class PostController below in file: src/Controller/PostController.php
```

Comment: are you sure you are on cakephp3? The locations, naming of certain files and missing entity is  2.*.

Comment: I dont know which version is this but when I ran the command in terminal it was showing cakephp 3.0.7

Comment: I guess the problem is using "test" as the name of your project. It could have conflict with the test suite. Try an other name.

Comment: then are you sure you are doing the 3.0 Tutorial? and not the 2.6 tutorial?

Comment: @AlexStallen Thanks, Your are right. I was using 2.6 tutorial. I just changed according 3.0 and it seems to works. But getting one error in View http://i.imgur.com/8aztTdF.png?1

Comment: The 3.x blog tutorial doesn't use posts, but articles, so you still seem to have 2.x leftovers.

Comment: Hi @ndm thanks. Now I completed the Articles demo and it is working :) Thanks you All :)

Comment: I am a java guy so I did not know that version changing in php framwork will affect all the functionality of the framework .

Answer (score 0):

Make following changes in your PostsController.php :

```
namespace App\Controller;
use App\Controller\AppController;

class PostsController extends AppController
{

    public function index()
    {
        $this->set('posts', $this->paginate($this->Posts));
        $this->set('_serialize', ['posts']);
    }

  [...]

}
```

in your URL try : `http://localhost:8888/test/posts`

Answer (score -1):

Make following changes in your Controller:

```
class PostsController extends AppController {

}
```

Comment: Getting `Error: Class 'App' not found 
File /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/test/src/Controller/PostsController.php 
Line: 3`

Comment: Make sure you have AppController.php file in your app/Controller folder and have you done any changes in this file?

Comment: I changed your line to `namespace App\Controller;` and now I am getting 
`Error: Call to a member function find() on boolean 
File /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/test/src/Controller/PostsController.php 
Line: 11`